# wpf make grid columns tnd rows from the viewmodel- c# side

Tags: c#, wpf

hii to everyone thank for help!!!
so i want to make my page with columns tnd rows - by the c# side in the view model
i bind the content xaml page to the grid prop in the view model and added some columns and rows but i cant choose the height or width i want - it do all rows and column auto same size no metter what
---you can see the view model code and what happens in the xaml wpf

```
 GameGrid = new Grid { ShowGridLines=true};
        //GameCanvas = new Canvas();
        var board = new BoardGame();
        //this.Grid.Children.Add(GameCanvas);
       // GameCanvas.Children.Add(GameGrid);
        //GameCanvas.Children.Add(whiteplayer);
        GameGrid.Background = new ImageBrush { ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("C:/Users/ofek/Desktop/1030 לימודים סלע/soa project/BackgammonAndChatProject4.2/BackgammonAndChatProject4/Ui/Images/backgaund.jpg")) };
        //GameGrid.Children.Add(GameCanvas);
        GameGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition{MaxHeight = 30});
        GameGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        GameGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        GameGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        GameGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        GameGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        GameGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { MaxHeight = 100 });
        GameGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        GameGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        GameGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        GameGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        GameGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        GameGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { MaxHeight = 50 });

        GameGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { MaxWidth = 168});  //0
        GameGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition ());                   //1
        GameGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());                   //2
        GameGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());                   //3
        GameGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());                   //4
        GameGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());                   //5
        GameGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());                   //6
        GameGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { MaxWidth = 394 });  //7 middle
        GameGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());                   //8
        GameGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());                   //9
        GameGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());                   //10
        GameGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());                   //11
        GameGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());                   //12
        GameGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());                   //13
        GameGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { MaxWidth = 168 });  //14
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xcb7i.png)

Comment: you really should define that Grid in the view using xaml, and use Width property instead of MaxWidth

Comment: Do you just want a matrix of equal sized cells?